# Is it possible to add VSIX XAML Toolbar to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015, vsix, visual-studio-shell

Is it possible to add XAML toolbar (instead of native Visual Studio in vsct file) to Visual Studio (in this case Visual Studio Shell)?
I cannot find any examples in the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you stick with using a VSCT resource, to keep your extension consistent with the look and feel of the IDE as a whole.

That being said, there is nothing stopping you from designing a toolwindow or custom designer that hosts XAML based toolbars. Some extenders choose to do this, but the buttons hosted are not VS commands, are not exposed to or discoverable via the Tools | Customize dialog, other extensions cannot automate or programmatically access them, and you lose the built in functionality to control visibility/enablement based on active contextUI guids.

Sincerely,